# How to write a variable in cache and after fetch it on pages reload? Apollo-Client

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I have:

```
var thisIndex = 1;
```

I want to write it in users cache and after reuse it whenever user opens the site page again. But I can't understand how.
Maybe you have some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if you want to use local storage then set the value in local stroage 

 var thisIndex = 1;
 var saveValueInLocal = localStorage.setItem("thisIndex");

 When Save and check the the value 

 var getValue = localStorage.getItem("thisIndex");
 if(getValue == 1){
 window.location.reload()
 }

If you want to save in cookie
  function createCookie(name, value, days) {
  var expires;
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
 }
 else {
    expires = "";
 }
 document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
 }

 Get the Value incookie

   function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
    if(getCookie){
      window.location.reload()
     }
```